# emacs weird characters on splash screen

Tags: emacs, character, splash-screen

I've recently downloaded emacs 24.2 for windows (i'm running vista 64bits) as my first attempt at emacs. When i start it up the characters in the splash screen as well as the tooltips for the menu items are all weird.

My guess is that the character (encodings?) is somehow messed up. 
Here's [a screenshot of my splash screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xstnuu68h07xbpf/emacs.png)

Thanks for trying to help me out, i appreciate it.

summary:
    - my splash screen shows weird characters
    - so do the tooltips for my buttons
    - i downloaded emacs 24.2 for windows [from here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-24.2-bin-i386.zip)
    - Can you help me get it showing english language?

Comment: Woah! Is your system set to a locale that uses a non-English script?

Comment: My system locale is Dutch however my keyboard layout is set to EN and i prefer to have my applications in English.
I have tried to edit the language via the GUI (options->Multilingual Enviroment->Set Language Enviroment) to Default, Dutch and English but none change anything. Also i re-downloaded emacs but the problem stayed. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yeah, it definitely looks like some kind of encoding issue. Do you have MinGW or Cygwin installed? I'm curious to know whether it looks OK when you run it in a terminal, or if you set your system locale to English (US/UK)

Comment: At the moment i have neither installed, i have to go for today but i will try your suggestion tomorrow and let you know the results. Tnx for helping

Answer (score 1):

To find what the problem font is, put the cursor on one of the gibberish characters in the splash screen, and press `C-u C-x =`.  If you can't read the buffer that comes up, then save it with C-x C-w, and view the file in some other editor.

For me, the following font is used, and it displays OK:

```
uniscribe:-outline-Arial-normal-normal-normal-sans-15-*-*-*-p-*-iso8859-1 (#x3A)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer everybody in this comment (not sure if it's the proper etiquette of stackoverflow). 
I've managed to fix the problem manually.

Emacs was using this font for me: 
`uniscribe:-outline-Helvetica-normal-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-p-*-iso8859-1 (#x73)` and `face: variable-pitch`
I edited the font family of the face from Sans-serif to Arial which fixed the problem. 

Thanks to @wvxwv and @JSON for helping me with the key shortcuts and advice.
Thanks to @Chris Barret for helping me out.
And thanks to @itlodge for suggeting unicad

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [unicad](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/unicad.el). 
It can solve the coding system problem automatically.